# jBPM No Remote Servers at Business-central

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jbpm

I am trying to run 'evaluation' sample application. after build and deployment, when I saw the execution server then there a message appears **No Remote Servers** This Deployment Unit is currently not in use by any Remote Servers. Please see below image [image: No Remote Servers]

I am using:

```
Windows 10

Java 11.0.12 (Redhat Open Java)

jbpm-server-7.70.0.Final-dist.zip

-------
JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final
JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final
JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 23.0.2.Final
```

When I saw logs(I am unable to get what is happening)

```
13:18:20,260 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.notification.WebSocketNotificationService] (default task-32) WebSocket notify on updated :: Updated server template{serverTemplate=ServerTemplateKey{id='sample-server', name='sample-server'}, resetBeforeUpdate=false}
13:18:20,260 WARN  [org.jbpm.workbench.ks.integration.KieServerIntegration] (default task-32) Failed to create kie server client for container evaluation_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT due to null
13:18:20,792 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.notification.WebSocketNotificationService] (default task-32) WebSocket notification about change requested on server ServerTemplateKey{id='sample-server', name='sample-server'} with container spec ContainerSpec{releasedId=evaluation:evaluation:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, configs={RULE=org.kie.server.controller.api.model.spec.RuleConfig@26ba3aaa, PROCESS=org.kie.server.controller.api.model.spec.ProcessConfig@bd2a4c03}, status=STARTED} ContainerSpecKey{id='evaluation_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT', containerName='evaluation', serverTemplateKey=ServerTemplateKey{id='sample-server', name='sample-server'}} with following result []
13:18:24,453 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.notification.WebSocketNotificationService] (Thread-210) WebSocket notification about change requested on server ServerTemplateKey{id='sample-server', name='sample-server'} with container spec ContainerSpec{releasedId=evaluation:evaluation:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, configs={RULE=org.kie.server.controller.api.model.spec.RuleConfig@26ba3aaa, PROCESS=org.kie.server.controller.api.model.spec.ProcessConfig@bd2a4c03}, status=STARTED} ContainerSpecKey{id='evaluation_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT', containerName='evaluation', serverTemplateKey=ServerTemplateKey{id='sample-server', name='sample-server'}} with following result []
```

Please guide me on what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance.